# Composite key to surrogate key

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key, business-intelligence, composite-key

I have a composite natural key from the data I'm getting. Using `composite_key=ID-PRODUCT_ID-CLIENT_ID-OFFICE_ID` , I want to convert this key in one surrogate key.

Example:

> composite_key = 55-001-234-01 to surrogate_key = 123; this is the
> normal scenario, sometimes the office code can change but I want to
> identify the record as the same Ex: composite_key = 55-001-234-02 to
> surrogate_key = 123.

- How can I implement this to create an Data Warehouse?
- How can I compare the composite key from one extraction to the other
  and understand if the field changed is something I can consider
  valid?

Comment: You would have a table mapping natural keys to surrogate keys.  Normally, though, you would just have the natural key in the data table, with a unique constraint, along with the surrogate key.

Comment: Okay, but how can I understand if the change in the composite key for example the office will result in the same surrogate key. in this case if I consider this records as the same because only the office changed and from a business perspective that is okay.

Comment: You'll have to write some rules, user defined function would seem to be a good way to go.

Comment: If office ID can change without meaning it should map to a different surrogate key, then I don't think it is really part of the natural key of your target structure.  Whichever tokens of that "natural key" that can change but not connote a change in the target record it should map to, strip them off.  For instance, if a change in any of ID, PRODUCT_ID, or CLIENT_ID should mean a different record, but OFFICE_ID doesn't matter, then your "real" natural key becomes ID-PRODUCT_ID-CLIENT_ID.  Use that as the basis of your comparison, and your intended match would occur.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for an algorithm to check for this difference, in terms of architecture and performance?

Comment: On another note 123 would to me not be a key in this table, but a group code, it's also been my experience that concatenated keys turn into a mess real quick. I'd have a unique surrogate key in this table and a compound  index.

Comment: No I don't all you've said is sometimes office_id doesn't matter. Not when, not why and not if it's the only "rule"...

Comment: The "problem" is: I have to compare records between monthly extractions, this records can change for business reason after some months. In this case the only key I can get for these records is composite. But if some field changes from one month to the other I want to map it to the same surrogate key.

Comment: I hate to go "all philosophical" on you, but if the composite key is mutable, is it really an identifier?  The surrogate key, should, at some level, identify not only a row in a table, but also an instance of an entity or a relationship in the subject matter.  Composite natural keys almost always identify relationships.  And if one of the component keys changes, then it isn't the same instance of the relationship anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two members with different OfficeID should map to the same surrogate key then it means OfficeID is simply not part of the composite key and is just a standard attribute with a type 2 (replace behaviour).

If your dimension is not too large, I'd suggest to use the simple Slowly Changing Dimension component avaialble in your ETL tool. If you don't have such a component, simply check with a lookup if the member is in your dimension is existing or not. If existing, apply an update to (eventually) change the OfficeID, if not apply an insert.

If you've a large dimension and performance issues, then it could be useful and improve performance by calculating a checksum for the set of attributes type 2. Your lookup should return this checksum and compare it to the checksum of your current row. If they are identique, the execution of the update statement is not needed.